# Cross compiling a kernel module issue in Makefile

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, yocto, kernel-module

I am working on intelX86_64 host machine and i am trying to cross compile a linux module for an ARM embedded board architecture.

I made a linux os for my board with yocto project and i build sdk cross compiler.

This is what i get when i run SDK environment script :

> arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon
>   -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a5 --sysroot=/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi

Basing on this, this is the Makefile i made :

```
MYY_KERNEL_DIR ?= /home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/sama5d27_som1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/4.14+gitAUTOINC+b733e44da2-r0/image/lib/modules/4.14.73-linux4sam-6.0-dirty/

ARCH ?= armv7-a

CROSS_COMPILE ?= arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc

obj-m += uleds.o

all:
        make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) M=$(PWD) -C $(MYY_KERNEL_DIR) modules

clean:
        make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) M=$(PWD) -C $(MYY_KERNEL_DIR) clean
```

And This is the error i get when i run MAKE command :

> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-
>   M=/home/gaston/shit -C
>   /home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/sama5d27_som1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/4.14+gitAUTOINC+b733e44da2-r0/image/lib/modules/4.14.73-linux4sam-6.0-dirty/
>   modules
>
> make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/sama5d27_som1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/4.14+gitAUTOINC+b733e44da2-r0/image/lib/modules/4.14.73-linux4sam-6.0-dirty'
>   make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/sama5d27_som1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/4.14+gitAUTOINC+b733e44da2-r0/image/lib/modules/4.14.73-linux4sam-6.0-dirty'
>   Makefile:10: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2

What error i'm making ? How can i fix this ? Thank you

Comment: Maybe your kernel is not compiled correctly (on the tmp directory of Yocto). Go to the kernel directory, source your environment, type  `make`, then retry to compile your module.

Comment: I solved the problem, my kernel path directory was wrong. Now it's working